# Same simple formula; Diff Workbooks= Different Results

Tags: excel, formula

This is so simple but yet so aggravating cause I dont know how to resolve this.

I have two different Excel files.

Basic formula of =L5/L4 where L5 is 3.3 and L4 is 4.3

That formula for the same exact data comes out different.

1st Excel file:  It comes out to 75.6%
2nd Excel file: It comes out to 76.7% (correct answer)

I've checked everything I could possibly check--version, formatting, everything.

Comment: are the values showing all the decimal places? using the buttons in the taskbar you can show fewer (or more) decimals in the numbers.

Comment: Formulas > Evaluate Formula?

Comment: Evaluate formula didnt show anything different. Yes, values are showing all decimal places.

Comment: Then there is some detail we are missing.

Comment: I have no clue.

Comment: Are `3.3` and `4.3` entered *manually*, or are there formulas in `L5` and `L4`?

Comment: Great question!  So, in 1st excel file, the 3.3 (L5) is from a formula (=M14) and 4.3 is manually entered.  On 2nd excel file, 3.3 and 4.3 are manually entered.

Comment: What's in `M14`? It's not equal to `3.3`.

Comment: 3.3 is in M14. I just double checked the sum and it adds up to 3.3. M14 is =SUM(M15:M19)

Comment: In a new cell, put `=M14=3.3`. The result will be `FALSE`.

Comment: Yes you are correct, lol. So although they add up correctly, something is wrong somewhere right? Cause M15-M19 are formulas also

Comment: No... it might be floating-point error. But in any case, you're dealing with two scenarios that aren't exactly the same.

Comment: Shoot, okay I need it to be both the same.

Comment: Thanks, you've helped figured out some of it

Comment: You might consider using `ROUND` when dividing, in case it's floating-point error, see [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result).

Comment: OMG the ROUND worked!!!!

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!